# What exactly is GoPro Protune?

Tags: gopro

Apparently the newer GoPro Hero cameras have a feature called "Protune" that gives better control over the image. I don't own a GoPro camera with Protune yet and I'm trying to figure out whether I still need a red filter for underwater shooting or if Protune can do the necessary color correction. Unfortunately I'm having a hard time finding out what it actually is.

[Some websites](https://www.spivo.com/blogs/news-updates/gopro-protune-settings-everything-you-need-to-know-before-you-shoot-with-it) say it's like manual mode:

> If you’ve ever played with a DSLR or mirrorless camera, [Protune is] kind of like switching the camera into manual mode.

[Other](https://www.scubaboard.com/community/threads/help-with-go-pro-3-underwater-settings-with-red-filter-caribbean-30-80-ft-protune.452744/) [websites](https://clicklikethis.com/what-is-protune-on-gopro/) say it's more like RAW:

> Protune = shorter battery life, bigger files

> Footage shot in Protune will generate larger files than what is shot in the default GoPro settings.